# Getting Error when Running WSGI Application on PythongAnywhere

Tags: python, aiohttp, pythonanywhere

I am getting an error when running my web app on PythonAnywhere.

The error is as follows:
`Error running WSGI application`
`TypeError: '_UnixSelectorEventLoop' object is not callable`

I'm suspecting that it has something to do with me using this in my `main.py`:

```
executor = ProcessPoolExecutor(2)
loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
dc_bot = loop.run_in_executor(executor, run_bot)
server = loop.run_in_executor(executor, run_server)
```

but I'm not sure how I could fix this as I am pretty new to using aiohttp. Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Show us the full error traceback!

Answer (score 1):

PythonAnywhere only supports WSGI for web applications and your aiohttp app is not a WSGI app, so it will not work.

Comment: I am trying to host a Discord bot that delivers messages to specified channels/threads whenever the webhooks are triggered, which explains the web server and the bot in my code. Can I know if it is the Discord bot that is not WSGI? Or could you define what is a WSGI app? Thanks!

Comment: https://wsgi.readthedocs.io/en/latest/what.html